# How to run jar through jenkins as a separate process?

Tags: jenkins, jar, pipeline

The question is this: I need to run a jar file on the node, in the Jenkins pipeline I write

```
       stage('Start bot') {
                  steps {
                      sh  'nohup java -jar /home/oomnpe/workspace/oomnpe_bot/target/oomnpe_bot-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar'
                  }
                }
```

But the build goes on endlessly after launching the jar, showing the logs of the application, if you make requests to it. If I stop the build, then the application also stops.

How to make the jar run on the remote machine and the build stop? Everywhere they write about "nohup", but I use it and there is no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. Check [this](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1473/running-a-background-process-in-pipeline-job) issue for more details.

```
withEnv(['JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE=dontkill']) {
    sh "nohup java -jar /home/oomnpe/workspace/oomnpe_bot/target/oomnpe_bot-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar &"
}
```